# Massive error in tikz-cd in 3 lines of code. Help!

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have 3 lines of code that is supposed to say "This is a very important equation" downarrow $x = 123$

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
                 This is a very important equation
                 \arrow[blue]{d}\\
                 $x = 123$ 
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

But I have received a tons of error just trying to get this simple line to work. The text is not printed correctly and the equation throws me an error.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything inside a `tikzcd` environment is already in math mode, so you don't need (and can't have) `$...$` inside it.  Cascading errors are common in TeX. Usually only the first error encountered is really relevant.

Since math mode isn't designed for writing text, I've added `amsmath` and used its `\text` macro for the first line.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \text{This is a very important equation}
    \arrow[blue]{d}\\
     x = 123
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]